# How do I prove that this product space is normal?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a compact subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$.

Let $C$ be a connected component of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A$.

Define $D=C\cup A$.

How do I prove that $D\times [0,1]$ is normal?

I tried to prove that $C\times [0,1]$ is normal, then show that $C\times [0,1] \cup A\times [0,1]$ is normal, but I'm stuck.

How do I prove this?

Comment: $D \times [0,1]$ is (homeomorphic to) a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ so it must be normal. (Every subspace of a metrizable space is metrizable, and all metrizable spaces are normal.)